# How to restore deleted Viber chats?

Tags: restore, delete, viber-messenger, chat

I lost all my viber chats & calls when I tried to migrate to a new phone. Thought transferring over the entire Viber folder to the new phone would do the trick but after activating Viber it didn't restore anything.

The problem is because I used the same number to activate viber it somehow deactivated viber on my old phone. I obviously activated it again but it deleted everything :(

**Is there a way to recover all my old viber chats?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this link? https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/2443290#.V4GpK3UrLQo it has instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hector, please do it *this* time as well: you know you can always [edit] your posts, do you?